# My image is not showing

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I saved image in sql server database.Now I am getting image from sql server database, by the following code but my image is showing in image control.But in this code i am saving this image in project directory. I want this image without saving, direct from my sql server database
What should i change in code.

```
    Dim result As Image = Nothing
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select * from infoimage", con)
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable("TABLE")
    da.Fill(dt)
    result = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(DirectCast(dt.Rows(0)(0), Byte())))
    result.Save("C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\GridViewExport   \img.jpg")
    Image1.ImageUrl = "~/img.jpg"
```

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ouuh, you should not paste image like this.
First, Image object itself is already an image, not a url.
So, once you've got an image from string, you should return it in response.write().
But better solution would be image handler.
Here is [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34084/Generic-Image-Handler-Using-IHttpHandler).

Comment: This is showing Image on complete web page.But i want this image in asp.net image control. What should i do to do it? guide me please.

Comment: Ok, I suggest to make it this way. You create a control, name it like and imagecontrol, or whatever you want which will just generate and image tag with image url, i.e. "<image src="blablabla<ID>.jpg>". Next step, you create an http handler which process all *.jpg url and return image by ID in return stream. Once browser downloads images in concurent requests anyway, the end result will be the same. Browser will request image in another http request, and will display image.

Comment: I am not getting sorry.If possible please give me a example.

Comment: in asnwer there is a link of how to create an image handler, just specify src attribute on your page like this "ImageHandler.aspx?tName=[groupname]&id=[idnumber]".